# Jenkins - windows command line task failure

Tags: windows, cakephp, jenkins, cmd, code-coverage

I have a trouble when running jenkins, I am using cakephp testing function to obtain the coverage XML. Trouble is that when it finishes the analysis it just says there is a failure in the build step and it makes the build to stop and fail.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\app>Console\cake.bat test app AllTests --stderr --log-junit junit.xml --coverage-clover clover.xml 


Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.5 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\app\
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
IIIIIIIIII.
'El nombre de password1'

'El nombre de password3'

'El nombre de wrongPass'
IIIIIIIIII.
'El nombre de password1'

'El nombre de password3'
.FFFFFFF

Time: 1.36 minutes, Memory: 10.75Mb

There were 7 failures:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "CityTest".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php:60
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:274
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:259
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php:440
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:209
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:66

2) Warning
No tests found in class "CountryTest".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php:60
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:274
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:259
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php:440
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:209
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:66

3) Warning
No tests found in class "CurriculumTest".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php:60
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:274
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:259
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php:440
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:209
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:66

4) Warning
No tests found in class "DepartamentTest".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php:60
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:274
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:259
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php:440
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:209
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:66

5) Warning
No tests found in class "LegalRepresentativeTest".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php:60
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:274
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:259
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php:440
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:209
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:66

6) Warning
No tests found in class "OrganizationTest".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php:60
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:274
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:259
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php:440
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:209
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:66

7) Warning
No tests found in class "UserTest".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php:60
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:274
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Command\TestShell.php:259
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php:440
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:209
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Proyecto Software\workspace\source\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php:66

FAILURES!
Tests: 30, Assertions: 12, Failures: 7, Incomplete: 20.

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
Build step 'Ejecutar un comando de Windows' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have no idea about what I should do, I tried changing the login property of the jenkins service because I thought it could have something to do with jenkins having no privilegies to write the XML files.

**NOTE:**
This is how I have written down the script in my jenkins task:

```
cd source
cd app
Console\cake.bat test app AllTests --stderr --log-junit junit.xml --coverage-clover clover.xml
```

Comment: Does that work when you execute the command from command line, not from Jenkins build step? I'd also strongly recommend to double quote `"` paths that contain spaces.

Comment: It actually works alright when running from command line and from the build step too. I mean, it's creating the junit.xml and coverage.xml files, and I even run sonar-runner manually to check if the files are readeable, and they are. But after creating them the task finishes it, somehow decides it was a failure. I am not sure but I think it has something to do with the exit code when it finishes the task. I don't know too much about cmd, but it is what I have read and I have no idea about how to check the exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when a failure (Not a failed assertion) happens, even when the shell finishes its task and everything ends up in a expected way, it returns an errorcode different to zero. Solving the problem and building again solved the problem.